# Javascript code not working after upgrade to karate 0.9.3

Tags: karate

The below function in feature files was working for version 0.9.2. Upgraded to 0.9.3 and this gives error : `javascript function call failed: Index: 0.0, Size: 0`. Code below:

```
var cnd = ['test1','test2'];

function set_filter(arg)
{
     var i;
     var filter = {filterValues:[]};
     for(i=0;i<arg.length;i++)
     {
         filter.filterValues[i] = arg[i];
     }
     return filter;
}

set_filter(cnd)
```

Also i was earlier able to push values in a javascript array using below, but this has also stopped working in 0.9.3. Get error:`javascript function call failed: TypeError: arr.push is not a function`

```
var arr = [];
arr.push('test1','test2');
```

Try the scenario below that works in 0.9.2 but reports error (mentioned above) in 0.9.3

```
Scenario: JS test
    * def filter_template =
    """
    function() {
    var filter_params = {
        filterValues:[]
    };
    return filter_params;
    }
    """
    * def template = call filter_template
    * def filter_condition = ['test1','test2']
    * def setFilter =
    """
      function(arg) {
        var i;
        var filter = arg.filter_template;
        for(i=0;i<arg.condition.length;i++)
        {
          filter.filterValues[i] = arg.condition[i];
        }
        return filter;
      }
    """
    * def getFilter = call setFilter { filter_template: '#(template)', condition: '#(filter_condition)' }
    * print getFilter
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you PLEASE make this a WORKING example that I can paste into a fresh `Scenario:` and try locally ? It is important for me to understand how you have mixed this JS with a feature file. or please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas I have edited the question and added working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've made the JS conversions stricter, everything will be a Java collection behind the scenes. If you make this change, things will start working:

```
filter.filterValues.set(i, arg.condition.get(i));
```

The same goes for `push()` - use `add()` or [`karate.appendTo(varname, value)`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-appendto) instead.

My strong recommendation is don't use too much of JS logic *especially* loops. Karate has functions such as `map()`, `forEach()` and `repeat()` to solve for these needs. Please refer the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

You will thank me later because it will make your scripts easier to understand and maintain. One reason why this is needed is to pave the way for us to change the JS engine in the future.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The following worked for me:
`filter.filterValues.add(arg.condition.get(i));`

I am marking this question answered. However, I am having difficulty in following the use of `karate.map()` or other built-in methods in my specific scenario. I will post a seperate question. Just an FYI - I have my filter template in a .js file. Each test case specifies its own filter condition and i use java script to add that condition into the filter template and execute the specific test. Not sure how will i bypass jaavscript to achieve this.

Comment: @rochitsen I'm not saying zero JS, but use the minimum possible and don't use loops at all. please do ask a separate question if needed and kindly keep it simple.